# if file uploads then unable to store data into database in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

i am unable to upload file in spring mvc actually when i am using **enctype="multipart/formdata"** at that time file will be uploaded but in this situation i am unable to store my data into database and if i remove **enctype="multipart/formdata"** it will be succefully store into database but file upload will not work

so now it is like switch on and off if one thing works then other will not

tell me the solution i am confused.

emp_form.jsp

```
<form class="stdform stdform2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/in_emp">
<p>
                                <label>Person image</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="file" name="filenm" id="filenm" class="input-xxlarge"  /></span>
                            </p> 
                            <p>
                                <label>User Name</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Person Name</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Address</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="add" id="add" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Gender</label>
                                <span class="field">
                                    <input type="radio" name="gen" value="Male" checked />Male
                                    <input type="radio" name="gen" value="Female" />Female</span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Contact No.</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="c_no" id="c_no" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Date Of Birth</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Email ID</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p><p>
                                <label>Qualification</label>
                                <span class="field"><input type="text" name="qual" id="qual" class="input-xxlarge" /></span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="stdformbutton">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Button</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset Button</button>
                            </p>
</form>
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/in_emp" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String insertEmp(@RequestParam("pname") String nm,Object command ,HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException
    {
        String path = req.getRealPath("/images/uploadimg");
        path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("\\build"));
        path = path + "\\web\\images\\uploadimg\\";
        DiskFileItemFactory d = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(d);
        try {
            List<FileItem> lst = uploader.parseRequest(req);
            for (FileItem fileItem : lst) {
                if(fileItem.isFormField()==false){
                    fileItem.write(new File(path+"/"+fileItem.getName()));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }
         res.setContentType("text/html");
        String abc="insert into `tbl_registration` (`person_name` ,`address` ,`gender` ,`contact_no` ,`dob` ,`email_id` ,`qualification` ,`designation_id`,`person_img`)VALUES ('"+nm+"','"+req.getParameter("add")+"','"+req.getParameter("gen")+"','"+req.getParameter("c_no")+"','2016-01-02','"+req.getParameter("email")+"','"+req.getParameter("qual")+"','"+req.getParameter("des")+"','"+req.getParameter("filenm")+"')" ;

        ServletContext sc=req.getSession().getServletContext();
        try{
           SqlServices ss=new SqlServices(sc.getRealPath("WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"));
           if(req.getParameter("gid")==null) {
                ss.persist(abc);
                String qry1="select reg_id from tbl_registration where person_name='"+nm+"' and contact_no='"+req.getParameter("c_no")+"'";
                List ls=ss.getlists(qry1);
                HashMap hm;
               if (ls != null) {
                   for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
                       hm = (HashMap) ls.get(i);
                       String inqry="insert into `tbl_login`(username,password,reg_id,user_type) values('"+req.getParameter("uname") +"','"+req.getParameter("pass")+"','"+hm.get("reg_id")+"',2)";
                       ss.persist(inqry);
                   }

               }

           }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
       return "tbl_employee";
    }
```

dispacher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="WebController"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

     <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

</beans>
```

Comment: at a first glance it's a problem of how you declared the file to be stored. Is it a @Blob or what?

Comment: it is not @Blob you can see my code clearly i am uploading file to folder in my server not in database